# .htaccess - remove query string from URL (no redirection)

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, query-string, httpserver

My URL is `http://www.example.com/eg1?redirect=xyz`, which should be `http://www.example.com/eg1`

The rewrite rule written for this is as follows:

```
RewriteCond %{Query_STRING} ^redirect=xyz$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /examples/$1? [L]
```

The redirection is working fine, but the query string remains appended. When i put `[R]` flag the question mark (`?`) at end works great and removes the query string, but with `[L]` flag its not working. And in my case I do not have redirection, just passing it to another directory which holds the content.

Answer (score 2):

The rules are fine:

```
RewriteCond %{Query_STRING} ^redirect=xyz$
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /examples/$1? [L]
```

If you want it to reflect at the address bar you will have to specify an *external redirect*. i.e. `R` with `Temporary Redirect` (`R=302`) or `Permanent Redirect` (`R=301`). Along with `L`. By default `R` does a temporary redirect.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /examples/$1? [R,L]
```

---

From comments:

Add `L` along with flsg `R`.

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R,L]
```

Comment: I dont want the intermediate URL to come on the address bar. Have you used [C] or [L] flag ? What i did was i tried temporarily redirecting it to a URL like this  'RewriteCond %{Query_STRING} ^redirect=xyz$ <br/> RewriteRule ^(.*)$ $1? [R] <br/>
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /examples/$1? [L]' This works but the problem is the last rule is getting executed always....so I was thinking of executing these 2 rules in conjunction, may be [C] or [N] flag can help. But they are not working as expected.